# How can I grab the user's IP address?

Tags: joomla-3.x, jinput, jrequest

I want to store the user's IP address in a Joomla 3.5 component;
with 2.5, I did a

```
$ip = JRequest::getVar('REMOTE_ADDR', '', 'SERVER');
```

Which is the most efficient way to get the IP address from a client using the JInput class, since JRequest is deprecated?

Comment: check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29342317/how-to-get-ip-address-by-session-in-joomla-using-sql

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please check this code -

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;

$ip = $jinput->server->get('REMOTE_ADDR', '', '');

//Here default value and filter are null, so you can write 

$ip = $jinput->server->get('REMOTE_ADDR');
```

By this you can get the ip address.

Comment: I don't know, what the 3rd parameter 'SERVER' should do. It's a filter, but not a standard one; should we change this to 'CMD' or  remove the 3rd parameter, because CMD is the default one? Or can I define a filter by myself in Joomla 3.x?

Comment: Yes *SERVER* wasnt required and you can leave the last parameter as Blank.

Comment: I believe the default value and filter are automatically `null`, so if they're not going be defined by you, then you can replace `->get('REMOTE_ADDR', '', '')` with `->get('REMOTE_ADDR')`

Answer (score 2):

I put a one-liner - and it works similar to your answer, because I do not use the object $jinput more than once; again thank you Joomler +1:

```
$ip = JFactory::getApplication()->input->server->get('REMOTE_ADDR','');
```

You could remove the second parameter too. If so, the $ip will be set to null if REMOTE_ADDR is not available.