# Getting wrong IP address from JFactory::getApplication()->input->server->get('REMOTE_ADDR','');

Tags: custom-module

I am attempting to validate the user IP address in a post. Joomla 3.5 and PHP 5.6.20.

I have read  [How can I grab the user's IP address?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/15988/how-can-i-grab-the-users-ip-address/15989#15989) and tried this out, but the wrong IP address is being returned.

Yes, my client is in a NAT but I checked the external port on the router for my external dhcp address, plus I compared against whatismyipaddress.com to ensure I am not (too) crazy.

Most likely, this is due to a proxied setup by my hosting provider (they are now using CloudFlare).  Any ideas on how to resolve the client ip address in this situation?

Comment: I verified that the address being returned by the posted code (see question title) is indeed owned by CloudFlareNet.

Comment: Maybe bad form to answer my own post, but I did locate the answer.  In my situation, the following line:  $clientip = JFactory::getApplication()->input->server->get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR',''); returns the correct value when the server is proxied!

Comment: You can post your comment-answer as an answer below and mark it as the one that solved your issue.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe bad form to answer my own post, but I did locate the answer once I moved beyond the Joomla documentation.

In my situation, the following line:

```
$clientip = JFactory::getApplication()->input->server->get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR','');
```

returns the correct value for the user ip address when the server is proxied!

Comment: Feel free to answer your own questions, it's not bad form. Regarding your answer, be aware that HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR can be easily spoofed. Unfortunately, I don't know a way around this.

Answer (score 1):

Just an FYI, there's no way to always get the real IP address as it may be proxied.

Based on [the following answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5785956/1362108), you could use something like this:

```
function getRealIpAddr()
{
    $server = JFactory::getApplication()->input->server;

    if (!empty($server->get('HTTP_CLIENT_IP')))    //check ip from share internet
    {
        $ip = $server->get('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
    }
    elseif (!empty($server->get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')))  //to check ip is pass from proxy
    {
        $ip = $server->get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
    }
    else
    {
        $ip = $server->get('REMOTE_ADDR');
    }

    return $ip;
}
```